# R function callback from C

Tags: r, c, rcpp

I have the following C function `callThisFromR.c` which I want to call from the R language,

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void callThisFromR  (
                    // some integer
                    int32_t integerFromR, // this is the length of the double vector `vec` to be passed again to R
                    // This is the R function passed to C: `getFuncFromR(vecLen, vec)`
                    double (* getFuncFromR) (
                                            int32_t , 
                                            double []
                                            ), 
                    char inputString[] , 
                    int32_t inputStringLen
                    ) {

    printf("This is the integer passed from R: %d\n", integerFromR);
    printf("This is the string passed from R: %s\n", inputString);
    printf("This is the string length passed from R: %d\n", inputStringLen);

    // Generate some double data to pass to R

    double *vec;

    vec = (double *) malloc( integerFromR * sizeof(*vec) );
    for( int i=0; i<integerFromR; i++ ) {
        vec[i] = (double) (i+1);
    }

    double result = getFuncFromR(integerFromR,vec);

    printf("This is the result of the R callback function passed from R: %f\n", result );
}
```

This C function is supposed to be called from within R and expects to receive an `int32` integer `integerFromR`, a string `inputString` and its length `inputStringLen`, as well as a callback function `getFuncFromR` from R. For example, here is the `main.c` C-equivalent of what I need to have in R,

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

double getFuncFromR (
                    int32_t vecLen, 
                    double vec[]
                    )
{
    double vecSum = 0.;
    for(int i = 0; i < vecLen; i++){
        vecSum += vec[i];
    }
    return vecSum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char inputString[] = "ThisIsTheStringPassedFromR2C";
    int32_t inputStringLen = strlen(inputString);
    int32_t integerFromR = 3;

    callThisFromR( integerFromR
                 , &getFuncFromR
                 , inputString
                 , inputStringLen
                 );
    return 0;
}
```

Easy in C. But to call `callThisFromR()` C-function from R and pass an R function `getFuncFromR()` has so far been like a nightmare. How can I write the C wrapper function? My exhaustive web search for an answer (including the Rcpp and R-Foreign-Language-Extension documentation) have led to nothing.

Comment: You may need to adjust your mental model. From a standalone `main()`, you can't "just call R".  The R interpreter needs to be embedded -- and [RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside) does that for you.  (Of course, you could omit RInside but you would still have to do all it does manually...  See the Writing R Extensions manual for details.)

Comment: Hi Dirk, perhaps my explanation was a little confusing. I do not want to call the main C function. I need to achieve what the C main function is doing from inside R. The main function is in R, it calls a C function named callThisFromR() in a shared library, and passes a callback R function to this C function. I can provide an R implementation of the main and the call back functions if needed. But what I do not know is to how to write the wrapper for the R functions .

Comment: Don't have the bandwidth to look at this in-depth at this time, but you may find ["Evaluating R Expressions from C"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#index-Evaluating-R-expressions-from-C) (Section 5.11 of Writing R Extensions) useful.

Comment: How to pass a user-defined R (and even C function) around is demonstrated in package RcppDE which extends DEoptim my making the objective function (that is optimized over) a compiled function.  All that is of course still called from R, so the `main()` and hence build process aspects, are different. I strongly urge OP to simplify and decompose his approach.